# Python: script to query all the data from mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have tried with this

```
for record in db.collection.find():
         print(record[0]+','+ record[1])
```

Here I am getting key error.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: i tried with

for record in db.collection.find().pretty():

o/p: pretty() method is not defined

Comment: Mongo queries return dicts, not lists. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to print with `record[0]` and `record[1]` here.

Answer (score 0):

The basic use of pymongo goes as follows :

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.Mongoclient('localhost',27017)
#parameter can be the database URL
db = client.dataBase
dbOutput = db.collection.find()
for tuple in dbOutput:
    print tuple[key1]
    print tuple[key2]
    .
    .
    .
    print tuple[keyN]
```

Other libraries can also be used. I find pymongo to be the simplest one. More documentation can be found [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for record in list(db.collection.find()):
     print(record[key]+','+ record[key])
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, record[0] is dict. You can use record[0][key].

Comment: i am getting this error:     "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: Mongo returns the data in a JSON object. The key is the JSON key, should be the string datatype. The integer index is actually the index of the JSON object in the JSON array that Mongo has given.

Comment: Can you print record?

Comment: Do you people have some hardcode sample script which will show all the data from mongoDB?

Comment: No, I am not able to print anything. same key error i am getting

Comment: @hari I have added an answer. Please check.